# Create folders on a remote Windows PC using C++?

Tags: c++, windows, mfc

How can I create folders on a remote Windows PC using C++?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Directly, you can't -- there would have to be a service on the remote machine which exposes that functionality for you.

If you're talking about a [server message block](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_message_block) scenario (i.e. "Windows Filesharing"), you can just call [`CreateDirectory`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363855.aspx) with a network path, i.e. `"\\\\computername\\share\\newFolder"`, but this requires the remote machine already be setup with an existing network share (I don't believe you can create said share remotely without A. admin rights on the target box, and B. some lessening of security settings to allow creation of shares remotely).

**EDIT**: (In response to the tag edit adding the MFC tag)
As far as how `CreateDirectory` is exposed in MFC, I'm not sure if there's an MFC wrapper around that function at all -- though there really doesn't need to be a wrapper because the function itself is self contained -- there'd be no benefit of putting it in a class.

Comment: There's usually the administrative share `\\ComputerName\C$`

Comment: @Billy : Is there a way by which we can move to parent folder of the share folder(`"\\\\computername\\share"`)?

Comment: @jackz: That would be a huge security vulnerability were it allowed. http://cwe.mitre.org/data/definitions/22.html

Comment: @BillyONeal: I tried using `\\\\computername\\share\\..\\ FolderName` .. but didnt work :(

Comment: @jackz It is explicitly disallowed. If it were allowed it would be a huge security hole.

Comment: If you find a way to do it I'm sure MSFT would love to pay you a bug bounty

Answer (score 0):

The typical way is to start by calling [`NetShareAdd`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb525384.aspx) to create a share to a path on the remote machine. To support creating things there, you'll normally want to specify at least `ACCESS_CREATE` for the share.

Once you've done that, you'll have a local path to the remote disk, and you can create a directory in it, just like you would with a local disk.